# Angular 1.5.7 xhr.onload doesn't get called after BACK

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, rest, xmlhttprequest

I've faced one great problem in my project. 
I have two pages on my SPA. First one is main app where all logic is concentrated and second one is login page to which I can go from my main page.

There are a lot of XHRs going from my main page.

When I go to login page and then press back some of requests don't complete succesfully.

When I do it again then all requests can't be handled.

During my debugging process I've found out that xhr.onload doesn't get called.

One of the most funniest things that in my network tab there are few requests which are completed(but xhr.onload wasn't called) and when I'm trying to make new requests they even aren't shown in network tab.

Has anyone ever faced problems like this?

My wrapper of http looks like this

```
request ({method, isHighPriority, callback, url, data, config}) {
    let task;

    switch (method) {
        case 'post':
        case 'put':
        case 'patch':
            task = this.$http[method].bind(null, url, data, config);
            break;
        default:
            task = this.$http[method].bind(null, url, config);
            break;
    }

    if (isHighPriority) {
        this.queueHightPriority.push(task, callback);
    } else {
        this.queueLowPriority.push(task,callback);
    }
}
```

Queues are queue from async lib.

```
    this.queueLowPriority = queue((task, callback) => {
        task().then(this.success(callback),
                    this.error(callback));
    }, ConnectionConstants.REQUESTS_LIMIT - HIGHT_PRIORITY_LIMIT);
    this.queueHightPriority = queue((task, callback) => {
        task().then(this.success(callback),
                    this.error(callback));
    }, HIGHT_PRIORITY_LIMIT);
```

I've tried to clear queues on back button. But tha main problem is deeper

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: @brk I've edited question.
this.$http creates simple XMLHttpRequest, sends it and waits for onload.